# any code snipt or plugin(jquery) for xml string(not xml file) parse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

i want to manipulate xml data simple ..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it in a jQuery element, like this:

```
var xml = "<thing><child>test</child></thing>";

var text = $(xml).find('child').text();
alert(text); //"test"
```

You can use most of the jQuery traversal methods to find what you want in the string...I'm not 100% positive, but this sounds like what you want.  This is a simple example for illustration purposes, but you can find more complex tutorials, [like this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery) and [this](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/) if you needs to dig a bit deeper...if you know jQuery and it's [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)/[selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) methods though, it should be pretty intuitive.